# What is the difference between isMail and isSMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, shared-hosting

I'm using PHPMailer and having a hard time getting isSMTP on bluehost to work.  I have been able to get isMail to work and am wondering what the difference is in sending mail.  Also, it seems that I'm getting a HELO or authentication error when trying to use isSMTP but bluehost says my setting are correct.  I'm using SSL and port 465.

Answer (score 14):

`isMail` and `isSMTP` are convenience methods to set the value of PHPMailer's `Mailer` property. This property determines how PHPMailer goes about sending a message after it has built it. With `isMail`, it's sent using PHP"s `mail` function. With `isSMTP`, it uses PHPMailer's accompanying `SMTP` class to act as an SMTP client, talking to a mail server directly.

Using the `mail` function requires that you have a mail server installed and running on your local machine - which, historically at least, has not been the case with Windows in particular. Generally using the mail function is fairly fast because it does not need to talk to a remote host, however, it's quite inefficient given that it actually acts as a front to the system's own `sendmail` binary, which simply opens a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost. You'll also get much less feedback - the `mail` function returns boolean value, so if it doesn't work it's hard to tell why it failed, and you will probably need to look in your mail server's logs to find out.

You can use the SMTP route to send to either local or remote mail servers, and typically SMTP to localhost is the fastest way to send. Because PHPMailer uses its own SMTP client to do this, it means it can see the whole SMTP conversation, and thus gets much better feedback when things don't work - you can set `SMTPDebug = 2` and see the whole conversation.

There are various thngs that can go wrong, and the best place to track down the root cause is to read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Why is it so hard to use isSMTP on blue host and godaddy but rather easy to use isMAIL?  They both say my credentials are correct but I get a HELO error which based on the php mailer doc is an authentication error. How do you track this down ?

Comment: As far a I'm aware GoDaddy requires you to use their internal mail server, and doesn't require authentication as it relies on your IP.