# PHPMailer: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) with godaddy

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, cpanel

I am getting the error:

```
    2020-05-03 02:33:55 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have looked at all GoDaddy articles and stack articles I can find and tried their solutions - such as changing ports, etc. I have also tried with both my Gmail and cPanel web/email accounts. Most solutions out there for this error, however, are not relating to GoDaddy, and their solutions are to do with XAMPP, etc.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

As reference, here is the PHP code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "abc@def.com";
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->SetFrom("abc@def.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("uvw@xyz.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

Comment: It’s impossible and pointless to use encryption when connecting to localhost. The PHPMailer troubleshooting guide has specific information about how to connect to GoDaddy’s mail servers.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out what was wrong:
Essentially, I just needed to replace `$mail->isSMTP();` with `$mail->isMail();` and it worked - just to let anyone else know if they have the same problem!

Comment: But then php won't use the SMTP service you might have subscribed to. Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39029466/6160662)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if you have provided incorrect information. However, you should make sure that the server's smtp port is not using **25**.

Comment: thank you - yes I have already tried both port 25 and 465 as well as other recommended ones on various forums :) I have now changed the Auth to false and added SSL = false - now It is taking forever to load (I have been waiting for about five minutes now) - do you know why this might be?

Comment: Which operating system and which panel do you use?

Comment: Nevermind - it has just loaded and the same error still shows up.

Comment: I am using Linux cPanel

Comment: Exim settings must be configured correctly on Cpanel. I had the problem you had before.

Comment: I have found out what was wrong and posted the solution - thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem 
i tried with SSL with port 465  then it said services is unavailable 
then i try this thing it solve my problem 
hopefully it solve also yours
1) Make sure you use 
$mail->IsSMTP();   for the authentication. Ismail is only working for the same server with mail function

2) This thing fix my problem
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";
 $mail->Port = 587;

i add these two lines now email sending is perfectly working 
earlier i face this error 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
but above thing solve my problem
hopefully it work for you 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Before sending emails using the Gmail's SMTP Server, you to make some of the security and permission level settings under your Google Account Security Settings.

2. change

> $mail->host  = "localhost";

to

> $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

3. 

Use real email for sender and receiver 'Make sure of the password'

4. change

> $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

to

> $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

```
   //tls for localhost and ssl for host server 'onligne'
```

may work for you :)